# Fabric.js : Set new image in canvas but canvas not changing

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs, nuxtjs

I add multiple image to canvas but I wanna to change first image added when click button. Now, the canvas not updating. I don't know why (I using fabric in nuxt js). **For example:** first the image will added to canvas in mounted then I click "add" button, the second image will added to canvas (addPattern method). After that, I click "change" button (changeImage) method but the canvas shown is not updating

**my code**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <canvas ref="can" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
        <button @click="addPattern">add</button>
        <button @click="changeImage">change</button>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c')
    mounted() {
        const ref = this.$refs.can
        canvas = new fabric.Canvas(ref)
        fabric.Image.fromURL('https//www.test.com/test.png', function (productImage) {
            productImage.set({
                width: 500,
                height: 500,
                selectable: false,
                name: 'product',
            })
            canvas.add(productImage)
        })
    },
    method: {
        addPattern() {
            fabric.Image.fromURL(image, function (patternImage) {
                patternImage.set({
                    selectable: true,
                })
                patternImage.scaleToHeight(120)
                patternImage.scaleToWidth(120)
                canvas.add(patternImage)
            })
        }
        changeImage() {
            canvas.item(0).set({
                src: "https//www.test.com/test2.png",
                width: 500,
                height: 500,
                selectable: false,
                name: 'product',
            })
            canvas.renderAll()
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Probably you can't change the image by setting `src`. I don't know why. I think you need to add a new image and remove the old one, it will work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the `src` attribute, you need to use `setSrc` method.

http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html#setSrc

```js
    canvas.item(0).set({
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        selectable: false,
        name: 'product',
    })
    .setSrc("https//www.test.com/test2.png", () => {
        canvas.renderAll()
    })
```